# Make dependent parameter available in Functor definition

Tags: interface, functor, idris

I have the following wrapper for `Vect`

```
data Foo : (r : Nat) -> (t: Type) -> Type where
  MkFoo : Vect r t -> Foo r t
```

I'd like to implement `Functor` for `Foo`, and use the value of `r` in the implementation, but I can't get it to compile.

```
Functor (Foo r) where
  map f (MkFoo v) = MkFoo (ff v) where
    ff : {r' : Nat} -> Vect r' a -> Vect r' b
```

gives

```
Error: While processing right hand side of map. r is not accessible in this
context.

Foo.idr:61:28--61:32
    |
 61 |   map f (MkFoo v) = MkFoo (ff v) where
    |                            ^^^^
```

This worked in Idris 1 but I can't figure out how to port it to Idris2. I've tried making `r` not erased, with

```
Functor ({r : _} -> Foo r) where
  map f (MkFoo v) = MkFoo (ff v) where
    ff : {r' : Nat} -> Vect r' a -> Vect r' b
```

but I get

```
Error: While processing type
of Functor implementation at Foo.idr:60:1--62:46. When
unifying Type -> Type and Type.
Mismatch between: Type -> Type and Type.

Foo.idr:60:21--60:26
    |
 60 | Functor ({r : _} -> Foo r) where
    |                     ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
{r : _} -> Functor (Foo r) where
  map f (MkFoo v) = MkFoo (ff v) where
    ff : {r' : Nat} -> Vect r' a -> Vect r' b
```